# Too Many Packages

Tags: packages

I'm writing a paper and I have too many packages. I use Overleaf, and it has "show/hide" for sections. Does someone know if I can do something like that in my preamble?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by too many packages, but you can put them in a separate file and then \input it into your main file if you want fewer lines in your main .tex file.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I ment. I was worried \input couldn't be used outside the document.

Comment: `\input` can be used in the preamble. `\include` on the other hand does some extra stuff and doesn't make much sense in the preamble.

Answer (score 1):

*Expanding from comment*

There are several ways to make your main .tex file shorter:

- Put your packages into a separate file and use `\input{}` in the preamble.
- [Write your own package](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Creating_Packages) which contains all settings and packages needed.
- Use something like [subfiles to make the document modular.](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Modular_Documents#Subfiles)